# JQuery ID + count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I dynamically create `checkbox` and `div`, I want to have different `id` for each of them (like id_1, id_2...).

The first value of my array is erased by the next value.
Currently, I create `checkbox` for each value I have in my array:

```
var containerCheckbox = $('#listCheckboxCategories');
// var listCheckboxCategories = $('#listCheckboxCategories');
var CheckboxCreate = '<input id="catCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="categoriesCheckbox" required/>';
var categoriesName = '<span id="catName"/>';

if (tileConfig.isThereFilterRadios == "Yes" && res !== undefined) {

  $('#ShowCategories').show();
  $('#containerCategories').show();

  $.each(res.list, function(index, cat) {
    //ToDo: inserer cat.name dans le span
    // categoriesName.html(cat.name)

    containerCheckbox.append(CheckboxCreate, categoriesName);
    $("#catName").html(cat.name);
  });
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: thank you, it return all the value but i still have the id's problem. (it return just after the first checkbox)

Comment: Try have an incrementor logic with your append that increments a value each time the action is performed and then concatenate that value to your id. That should give them a different id every time.

Comment: Try @Martin's suggestion or you can use some utility library like `underscore.js`? It provides lot of other utilities besides `_.uniqueId` (https://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) which you can use in future. It comes handy at time.

Comment: Keep in mind that an id is not the only way to access elements, be it via scripting or CSS. Depending on what you think you need those ids for, you might not _actually_ need them ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function to return the checkbox element, that way you could pass a variable into the function (eg index) to add to the html to make each id unique

for example

```
createCheckbox = function (index) {
 return '<input id="catCheckbox_' + index + '" type="checkbox" name="categoriesCheckbox" required/>';
}

var containerCheckbox = $('#listCheckboxCategories');
var categoriesName = '<span id="catName"/>';

if (tileConfig.isThereFilterRadios == "Yes" && res !== undefined) {

  $('#ShowCategories').show();
  $('#containerCategories').show();

  $.each(res.list, function(index, cat) {
    containerCheckbox.append(createCheckbox(index), categoriesName);
    $("#catName").html(cat.name);
  });
}
```